# Jest mocking request.res.setHeader always return error - not a function

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

My login method using request.res.setHeader() to return refresh token info in header, in unit test, I try to mock this function, but always got error - "TypeError: request.res.setHeader is not a function", if I remove this request.res.setHeader(...) line, test passed. Following is my mocking script for request:

```
export const mockRequest = {
  user: readerStub(),
  res: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { setHeader: jest.fn() };
  }),
};
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem here?

Complete login unit is here

```
async login(request) {
    const readerID = request.user._id;
    const accessToken = this.getJwtAccessToken(readerID);
    const refreshToken = this.getCookieJwtRefreshToken(readerID);
    await this.setRefreshToken(refreshToken[1], readerID);
    request.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', refreshToken[0]);
    //create the log for success activity
    this.logger.info(`Success login for reader ${request.user.username}`);
    return {
      token_info: accessToken,
      expireIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_TIMER,
    };
  }
```

The unit testing code is here

```
describe('login', () => {
    describe('when login is called', () => {
      let token: TAccessToken;

      beforeEach(async () => {
        jest
          .spyOn(readerService, 'getJwtAccessToken')
          .mockImplementationOnce(() => accessTokenStub().token_info);
        jest
          .spyOn(readerService, 'getCookieJwtRefreshToken')
          .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            return [
              refreshTokenStub().refreshToken_Cookie,
              refreshTokenStub().refreshToken,
            ];
          });
        jest
          .spyOn(readerService, 'setRefreshToken')
          .mockImplementationOnce(async () => Promise.resolve('OK'));
        token = await readerService.login(mockRequest);
      });

      test('then it should call setRefreshToken', () => {
        expect(readerService.setRefreshToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          refreshTokenStub().refreshToken,
          readerStub()._id,
        );
      });

      test('then it should return a access token in body', () => {
        expect(token).toEqual(accessTokenStub());
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: can you please accept the answer since as per your comment, the solution worked for you? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` itself is not a function, so when you do `res: jest.fn()...` you'll never get into the mock, because it's not called as `res()`, it just called as `res.setHeader`. Instead of doing `res: jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=> ({ setHeader: jest.fn() }))` you should just do `res: { setHeader: jest.fn() }`